# can't override theme files in wordpress child theme

Tags: php, wordpress, wordpress-theming

I have coruscate premium theme and I am making a child theme for it. To modify the php file I copied the file and paste it in the child theme including directory path. But it doesn't work.
I copied framework/widget.php file from parent theme and paste it to child theme folder but it didn't work.
 What is the correct method of overriding the parent theme files?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You need a style.css file set up in your child theme that tells wordpress it is the child etc... then you select your child theme within admin and then things will work. See https://codex.wordpress.org/Child_Themes for more information.

Answer (score 0):

For creating a child theme, make a folder inside your 'themes' folder with you child theme name. Now the child theme should have a style sheet in it which is a must. So add a style sheet and the beginning of the child theme style sheet should be as follows:

```
/*  
    Theme Name: (theme name) Child
    Theme URI: (give URL)
    Description: (give description)
    Version: (give your version)
    Author: (author name)
    Author URI: (give URL)
    Template: (name of parent theme)
    */
```

Of these the very important thing is the 'Template' which is the parent theme name. To avoid confusion take the name of parent theme from the parent theme style sheet.

Now the second thing is the functions of your child theme. Just add a php file with the name functions.php and place the below code

```
<?php
add_action( 'wp_enqueue_scripts', 'my_theme_enqueue_styles' );
function my_theme_enqueue_styles() {
    wp_enqueue_style( 'parent-style', get_template_directory_uri() . '/style.css' );

}
?>
```

It worked for me :)